# Why Twitter Feed isn't loading into my Website?

Tags: html, css, jquery, twitter

I am creating a Website using HTML5 and CSS3 myself. I am using jquery.tweet.js javascript file for showing my twitter feed into my website. And, I added below jQuery code into my body element:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#latest-tweets').tweet({
            username: 'sumonbdinfo',
            count:1,
            loading_text: "loading tweets..."
        });
    });
</script>
```

But, in my website is only now showing "loading tweets..." text, not showing my Twitter Feeds anymore.

Also, I added the jquery.tweet.js file into my head element and added jquery into my head element. But, still it's not showing on my website.

Should I put the above code into my head element of my website or I just added it in right place?

I pasted below the jquery.tweet.js file what I'm using for showing tweets on my website.

```
(function(a){a.fn.tweet=function(c){var n=a.extend({username:null,list:null,favorites:false,query:null,avatar_size:null,count:3,fetch:null,page:1,retweets:true,intro_text:null,outro_text:null,join_text:null,auto_join_text_default:"i said,",auto_join_text_ed:"i",auto_join_text_ing:"i am",auto_join_text_reply:"i replied to",auto_join_text_url:"i was looking at",loading_text:null,refresh_interval:null,twitter_url:"twitter.com",twitter_api_url:"api.twitter.com",twitter_search_url:"search.twitter.com",template:"{avatar}{time}{join}{text}",comparator:function(p,o){return o.tweet_time-p.tweet_time},filter:function(o){return true}},c);var b=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;function l(q,r){if(typeof q==="string"){var o=q;for(var p in r){var s=r[p];o=o.replace(new RegExp("{"+p+"}","g"),s===null?"":s)}return o}else{return q(r)}}a.extend({tweet:{t:l}});function f(p,o){return function(){var q=[];this.each(function(){q.push(this.replace(p,o))});return a(q)}}function k(o){return o.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"^&gt;")}a.fn.extend({linkUser:f(/(^|[\W])@(\w+)/gi,'$1@<a href="http://'+n.twitter_url+'/$2">$2</a>'),linkHash:f(/(?:^| )[\#]+([\w\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0600-\u06ff]+)/gi,' <a href="http://'+n.twitter_search_url+"/search?q=&tag=$1&lang=all"+((n.username&&n.username.length==1&&!n.list)?"&from="+n.username.join("%2BOR%2B"):"")+'">#$1</a>'),capAwesome:f(/\b(awesome)\b/gi,'<span class="awesome">$1</span>'),capEpic:f(/\b(epic)\b/gi,'<span class="epic">$1</span>'),makeHeart:f(/(&lt;)+[3]/gi,"<tt class='heart'>&#x2665;</tt>")});function e(p,o){return p.replace(b,function(s){var r=(/^[a-z]+:/i).test(s)?s:"http://"+s;var u=s;for(var t=0;t<o.length;++t){var q=o[t];if(q.url==r&&q.expanded_url){r=q.expanded_url;u=q.display_url;break}}return'<a href="'+k(r)+'">'+k(u)+"</a>"})}function j(o){return Date.parse(o.replace(/^([a-z]{3})( [a-z]{3} \d\d?)(.*)( \d{4})$/i,"$1,$2$4$3"))}function h(o){var q=(arguments.length>1)?arguments[1]:new Date();var s=parseInt((q.getTime()-o)/1000,10);var p="";if(s<1){p="just now"}else{if(s<60){p=s+" seconds ago"}else{if(s<120){p="a minute ago"}else{if(s<(45*60)){p=(parseInt(s/60,10)).toString()+" minutes ago"}else{if(s<(2*60*60)){p="an hour ago"}else{if(s<(24*60*60)){p=""+(parseInt(s/3600,10)).toString()+" hours ago"}else{if(s<(48*60*60)){p="a day ago"}else{p=(parseInt(s/86400,10)).toString()+" days ago"}}}}}}}return"about "+p}function g(o){if(o.match(/^(@([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)) .*/i)){return n.auto_join_text_reply}else{if(o.match(b)){return n.auto_join_text_url}else{if(o.match(/^((\w+ed)|just) .*/im)){return n.auto_join_text_ed}else{if(o.match(/^(\w*ing) .*/i)){return n.auto_join_text_ing}else{return n.auto_join_text_default}}}}}function d(){var p=("https:"==document.location.protocol?"https:":"http:");var o=(n.fetch===null)?n.count:n.fetch;var r="&include_entities=1&callback=?";if(n.list){return p+"//"+n.twitter_api_url+"/1/"+n.username[0]+"/lists/"+n.list+"/statuses.json?page="+n.page+"&per_page="+o+r}else{if(n.favorites){return p+"//"+n.twitter_api_url+"/favorites/"+n.username[0]+".json?page="+n.page+"&count="+o+r}else{if(n.query===null&&n.username.length==1){return p+"//"+n.twitter_api_url+"/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+n.username[0]+"&count="+o+(n.retweets?"&include_rts=1":"")+"&page="+n.page+r}else{var q=(n.query||"from:"+n.username.join(" OR from:"));return p+"//"+n.twitter_search_url+"/search.json?&q="+encodeURIComponent(q)+"&rpp="+o+"&page="+n.page+r}}}}function m(o,p){if(p){return("user" in o)?o.user.profile_image_url_https:m(o,false).replace(/^http:\/\/[a-z0-9]{1,3}\.twimg\.com\//,"https://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/")}else{return o.profile_image_url||o.user.profile_image_url}}function i(p){var q={};q.item=p;q.source=p.source;q.screen_name=p.from_user||p.user.screen_name;q.avatar_size=n.avatar_size;q.avatar_url=m(p,(document.location.protocol==="https:"));q.retweet=typeof(p.retweeted_status)!="undefined";q.tweet_time=j(p.created_at);q.join_text=n.join_text=="auto"?g(p.text):n.join_text;q.tweet_id=p.id_str;q.twitter_base="http://"+n.twitter_url+"/";q.user_url=q.twitter_base+q.screen_name;q.tweet_url=q.user_url+"/status/"+q.tweet_id;q.reply_url=q.twitter_base+"intent/tweet?in_reply_to="+q.tweet_id;q.retweet_url=q.twitter_base+"intent/retweet?tweet_id="+q.tweet_id;q.favorite_url=q.twitter_base+"intent/favorite?tweet_id="+q.tweet_id;q.retweeted_screen_name=q.retweet&&p.retweeted_status.user.screen_name;q.tweet_relative_time=h(q.tweet_time);q.entities=p.entities?(p.entities.urls||[]).concat(p.entities.media||[]):[];q.tweet_raw_text=q.retweet?("RT @"+q.retweeted_screen_name+" "+p.retweeted_status.text):p.text;q.tweet_text=a([e(q.tweet_raw_text,q.entities)]).linkUser().linkHash()[0];q.tweet_text_fancy=a([q.tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0];q.user=l('<a class="tweet_user" href="{user_url}">{screen_name}</a>',q);q.join=n.join_text?l(' <span class="tweet_join">{join_text}</span> ',q):" ";q.avatar=q.avatar_size?l('<a class="tweet_avatar" href="{user_url}"><img src="{avatar_url}" height="{avatar_size}" width="{avatar_size}" alt="{screen_name}\'s avatar" title="{screen_name}\'s avatar" border="0"/></a>',q):"";q.time=l('<span class="tweet_time"><a href="{tweet_url}" title="view tweet on twitter">{tweet_relative_time}</a></span>',q);q.text=l('<span class="tweet_text">{tweet_text_fancy}</span>',q);q.reply_action=l('<a class="tweet_action tweet_reply" href="{reply_url}">reply</a>',q);q.retweet_action=l('<a class="tweet_action tweet_retweet" href="{retweet_url}">retweet</a>',q);q.favorite_action=l('<a class="tweet_action tweet_favorite" href="{favorite_url}">favorite</a>',q);return q}return this.each(function(p,s){var r=a('<ul class="tweet_list">');var q='<p class="tweet_intro">'+n.intro_text+"</p>";var o='<p class="tweet_outro">'+n.outro_text+"</p>";var t=a('<p class="loading">'+n.loading_text+"</p>");if(n.username&&typeof(n.username)=="string"){n.username=[n.username]}a(s).bind("tweet:load",function(){if(n.loading_text){a(s).empty().append(t)}a.getJSON(d(),function(u){a(s).empty().append(r);if(n.intro_text){r.before(q)}r.empty();var v=a.map(u.results||u,i);v=a.grep(v,n.filter).sort(n.comparator).slice(0,n.count);r.append(a.map(v,function(w){return"<li>"+l(n.template,w)+"</li>"}).join("")).children("li:first").addClass("tweet_first").end().children("li:odd").addClass("tweet_even").end().children("li:even").addClass("tweet_odd");if(n.outro_text){r.after(o)}a(s).trigger("loaded").trigger((v.length===0?"empty":"full"));if(n.refresh_interval){window.setTimeout(function(){a(s).trigger("tweet:load")},1000*n.refresh_interval)}})}).trigger("tweet:load")})}})(jQuery);
```

So, please help me anyone how may I fix this issue? It would be really very helpful for me man. Waiting for anyone answers here!

Comment: Do you know what version of the Twitter API this jquery.tweet.js is using? I seem to recall seeing (on Twitter) that v1.1 of the Twitter API was recently turned off, so that may be your problem.

Comment: @Karl 1.0 was removed and replaced by 1.1, but yes, that seems to be the problem. Use another library, there are many to choose from.

Comment: Hi @Karl No, I don't know what the version of Twitter API is using this jquery.tweet.js file. Is there any way to check it and if it's using the old version of Twitter API then how may I using the Update version of Twitter API? Where I should change? And, Did I put the jQuery code in the right place? I meant in the body element or in the head element?

Comment: @Juhana Thanks, sorry I got the version numbers wrong.

Comment: Hi @Juhana am I using good script for showing Twitter Feeds? Or which one do you suggest me for using? Do you've any of them?

Comment: @SumonKhan - yes, putting the jQuery in the head or body will work, because you are using the jQuery ready function so it will wait until the DOM is loaded before executing.

Comment: @SumonKhan - you should be able to see what is being called by using developer tools in your browser of choice (F12 tools for IE, Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools). The Network tab on any of those tools will show the calls being made by the browser and the version of the API should be in the request to Twitter.

Comment: @Karl Thank you Man. I will keep it in my mind and what ready function does too :)

Would you please answer my below question too in the comment?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot continue using the seaofclouds tweet.js and expect to pull tweets like you used to last month. The cause of this was that twitter 1.0 api was recently replaced with 1.1 - https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired. The author of ***jquery.tweet.js*** talks about the API changes and the state of his plugin here: https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/#important-note-about-twitters-api-changes-in-2013 and a separate discussion can be found here: https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/issues/264 with an alternative (which works) - https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod.

***Tweet.js-Mod*** is a modified version of the original ***jquery.tweet.js*** and uses a php script to access twitter's API version 1.1.

Installation instructions can be found here: https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod#how-to-use

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your nice answer to me. What did this line mean actually: If you keep index.php somewhere besides /twitter/, specify the path to it via the modpath option, relative to your domain. For example:
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.twitterfeed').tweet({
    modpath: '/assets/twitter/',
    count: 5,
    loading_text: 'loading twitter feed...',
    /* etc... */
});
</script>`

I will be using my index.html in my root directory and javascript file will be in js folder. Then what I should put in mod option?

Please, make me clear this things!

Comment: @SumonKhan the Tweet.js-Mod plugin is 'wired' to look for the index.php in a folder called 'twitter' in the root directory of the site but however if you do not want to/unable to create a folder in the root directory and you have the php file inside another sub directory you would need to use the 'modpath' option to point the plugin to your new index.php path.

Comment: @SumonKhan - Your modpath value should look like this:

`modpath: '/js/'`

Comment: Hi @darshanags  So, if I don't put my index.php or index.html file in any folder or sub-directory then I don't have to use 'modpath', am I right? If yes then should I just remove the 'modpath' line of code or what?

Comment: @SumonKhan no, you would still need to use the modpath to point the script to where the index.php is. But I would imagine that having an index.php and index.html both in the root directory might cause you trouble depending on how your web server is setup. I would suggest either having this folder https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod/tree/master/twitter in the root of your site or to have the contents of that folder in another sub directory.

Comment: Hi @darshanags So, I've to locate the jquery.tweet.js file, am I correct?

And, one last question to you! What did the below question actually?

_after creating your app, configure index.php with your OAuth credentials_

Comment: @SumonKhan you need to create a twitter app using a set of twitter credentials at your disposal via this link: https://dev.twitter.com/apps and configure the index.php using the information that you receive after creating the app. It's pretty simple, give it a try! :)

Comment: @darshanags but I am not using PHP. I am using HTML website actually. What will be happened if I don't use it? Is this will still work?

Comment: I could really use some help from anyone who has successfully implemented the Tweet.js-Mod for seaofclouds.

I can get as far as creating two .json files, but only if I remove this line:

`if(empty($_POST)) { die(); }`

One of the .json files is the array of tweets I wanted, the other is an error message from the server telling me "The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)"

The tweets from the .json file do not display on the page.

I feel like I'm tantalisingly close but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a major change to how Twitter is handling requests, version 1.0 of their API allowed unauthenticated requests, but now that has changed where Twitter is pushing developers to use their embedded timelines, which requires authentication.

[Discussion of Twitter transition from v1.0 to v1.1](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Let me warn you about using the  https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod#how-to-use
It works perfectly but some of your clients where the website runs may have this ERROR

ERROR:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.getmytweets.co.uk/?screenname=philipbeel&limit=5&undefined=undefined. Origin http://plugins.theodin.co.uk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Also this method does not use the Oauth method and your security can be compromised. Twitter highly discourages the uses of client side authentication.

Your solution has 2 parts

1. Use a php based Oauth Script to retrieve you tweets in JSON format
2. Using Jquery format the JSON and show it into your website

SIMPLE AND SECURE.

HERE IS A COMPLETE TUTORIAL
http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/